# Convex Decomposition of a Complex Polygon?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, geometry

With both my 2D physics system (box2D) and OpenGL, conplex polygons need to be decomposed into convex polygons.  Ensuring models conform to this is easy.  However, I would also like to edit the polygons as the simulation progresses, so I need a dynamic way of fracturing existing polygons into more polygons that are still convex.

I hope this drawing helps describe what I'm after:

[image: image aid]

My Question is, Is there an existing library that can accomplish this?  And if not, what would be the least error prone way of doing it myself?

(I was looking through Boost, which has both a Geometry and a Polygon module, but the documentation is proving a little too esoteric for me to know if either can do what I want.)

Comment: Definitely not understanding your equations--B - A should be that chunk of B which *doesn't* overlap A, and I don't know what A*B could possibly mean, certainly not how it could equal C3

Comment: @Matt - Sorry, my equations are backwards.  A * B should find the intersection, and B - A should find the non-overlapping section of A.  The operators themselves, I just threw in for the sake of needing operators, I'm not sure what the actual operator for this sort of thing would be.

Comment: Intersection is traditionally represented with an upside-down u shape, ^ is probably the best you can do with ascii.  The non-overlapping section of A is A - B, which is precisely *not* B_A!  Pretty confusing.  Also, is a method for finding the vertices formed by the intersecting edges of A and B what you want?

Comment: @Clairvoire I think you're looking for the intersection operator ∩. To do a difference you need a complement: B-A is B∩!A in set notation, and the intersection is just B∩A

Comment: @Matt - I imagine it would be a part of it, but the main thing giving me trouble is finding the right existing vertices to connect them to, to form convex polygons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/research/CG/applets/convex_decomp/Default.html) is what you're looking for.

As for finding the intersection, that's just a little algebra; for any two line segments it's easy to derive the corresponding lines ('rise over run', etc.),

> y = a1*x + b1
>
> y = a2*x + b2

then the point of intersection (x', y') is

> x' = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2)
>
> y' = a1*x' + b1

Now of course that's the point of intersection of the *lines*, to determine that the line segments actually intersect you'll need to do simple range checking with the x, y coordinates.